# Include all values in a secondary group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g, group-by

I'm trying to write a SQL statement to get the sum of a value for all children within a parent:

```
SELECT parent, child, sum(val)
FROM table_a
GROUP BY parent, child
ORDER BY parent, child
```

This is giving me:

```
Parent1  Child1  123 
Parent1  Child2  456
Parent2  Child1  789
Parent3  Child1   12
Parent3  Child2  345
```

What I want is to get all the children, not just the ones beneath the parent for each parent and assign it a value of 0 if it does not have a record.  So for example:

```
Parent1  Child1  123 
Parent1  Child2  456
Parent2  Child1  789
Parent2  Child2    0
Parent3  Child1   12
Parent3  Child2  345
```

Can I do this with a GROUP BY clause?  Or do I need to use sub queries?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to cross join table_a on itself and then do your group by across the synthetic rows. I'm not sure of the Oracle syntax, otherwise I'd write some actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can brute force the problem with inline views but this is likely to be rather inefficient

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 1 parent, 1 child, 123 val from dual union all
  3    select 1, 2, 456 from dual union all
  4    select 2, 1, 789 from dual union all
  5    select 3, 1, 12 from dual union all
  6    select 3, 2, 345 from dual
  7  )
  8  select p.parent, c.child, nvl(sum(val),0)
  9    from (select distinct parent from t) p
 10         cross join (select distinct child from t) c
 11         full outer join t on (t.parent = p.parent and t.child = c.child)
 12*  group by p.parent, c.child
SQL> /

    PARENT      CHILD NVL(SUM(VAL),0)
---------- ---------- ---------------
         2          1             789
         1          2             456
         3          1              12
         1          1             123
         2          2               0
         3          2             345

6 rows selected.
```